# Mount IMG file as CD on Mac?

Tags: macos, virtualbox, mount, compact-disc

I'm trying to install Windows on VirtualBox, but it's not recognizing my physical CD drive.  So instead I want to mount the IMG file of the install disc as a CD (like you would with Daemon Tools or Virtual Clone Drive in Windows).

Is this possible on the Mac without forking out $80 for Toast?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You double click the IMG file and the OS will mount a drive with the information. After you mount it, go to the **Disk Utility** and save the drive as a CDR disc image... Simple as that, at least, in Lion.

Comment: *The following disk images couldn't be opened - no mountable file system*

Comment: I get the same error: "no mountable file system"

Answer (score 4):

First, have you tried renaming the .IMG to .ISO or .DMG? Sometimes I've found that to work, depending on how the .IMG was created.

Alternatively, give [AnyToISO](http://www.crystalidea.com/anytoiso) a whirl. It would require you to convert the image, rather than mount it the way Toast would, but that should only inconvenience you once. You can try out the Lite (free) version to make sure the import format (.img) is supported.

Answer (score 1):

Virtualbox deals with .iso, .cdr and .dmg cd images, so, as you seem to have a physical disk, why not [create an image file in say .iso format using dd](https://web.archive.org/web/20140829192111/http://www.slashdotdash.net/2006/08/14/create-iso-cd-dvd-image-with-mac-os-x-tiger-10-4/)?

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your VirtualBox VM to use a disk image located on your Mac host system for the CD/DVD drive of your virtual machine. [See the VirtualBox manual](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch03.html#settings-storage).

Comment: True. But doesn't work with IMG files as far as I can tell.

Comment: @user [img](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IMG_(file_format)) is a rather generic file extension. Depending on which of the variants it is (iso is very common), it could work -- try renaming the file.